# Edit and save updated polygon coordinates in google maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my rails application I have implemented a google maps using the polygon drawing tool. I have been able to add coordinates and save these to my database successfully.

The problem i'm having is when a user wants to edit and save any changes made to the polygon shape. How do i implement this function? My best guess is to use a conditional to see if the database has any saved coordinates, if so, load them in a listener?

**HTML**

```
<div style='width: 100%;'>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:map_coords, value = nil, html_options = {id: 'propertyCoordinates'}) %>
```

**Javascript**

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  center: { lat: -40.6892, lng: 74.0445 },
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
});
        
var polyOptions = {
  strokeWeight: 0,
  fillOpacity: 0.45,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
};
// loads databased saved coordinates
var propertyCoords = [<%= @property.coordinates %>];
var points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < propertyCoords.length; i++) {
  points.push({
   lat: propertyCoords[i][0],
   lng: propertyCoords[i][1]
  });
}
                    
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
 drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
 drawingControlOptions: {
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
  drawingModes: ["polygon"]
},
 polylineOptions: {
  editable: true,
  draggable: true
 },
 rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
 circleOptions: polyOptions,
 polygonOptions: polyOptions,
 map: map
});
            
if (typeof points !== 'undefined') {
 // My guess is to use a conditional statement to check if the map has any coordinates saved?
 } else {
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
  if (e.type !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
  // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
  drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
  // mouses down on it.
  var newShape = e.overlay;
  newShape.type = e.type;
  google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
   if (e.vertex !== undefined) {
    if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
     var path = newShape.getPaths().getAt(e.path);
      path.removeAt(e.vertex);
      if (path.length < 3) {
       newShape.setMap(null);
      }
     }
    }
  setSelection(newShape);
  });
 }
  var coords = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
  document.getElementById("propertyCoordinates").value = coords;
  });
 }
} // END function initMap()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is the polygon editing functionality. My [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uuyhvg) goes something like this:

1. Draw a polygon if you already have user-saved coordinates. Then fit the map bounds to the poly's bounds. For this you'll probably need a `getBounds` polyfill.
2. Make the polygon editable so you can listen to its points' changes. Check the function `enableCoordinatesChangedEvent`.
3. Listen to the changes & extract the new polygon points. Look for function `extractPolygonPoints`.

Then proceed with your business logic.

*FYI you'll need to put your own API key at the bottom of the stackblitz `index.html`. Look for `YOUR_KEY`.*

Comment: Amazing. Thanks @joe. One slight change was changing `document.getElementById("propertyCoordinates").value = coords;` to `var coords = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
  document.getElementById("propertyCoordinates").value = coords;`  to save the updated coordinates.